# Override volume key in Android in pop up menus/notifications

Tags: android, volume

I have been trying to figure this out and know that overriding the volume keys is not the most ideal thing but its the one real buttons on every Android device which is needed for my application.  Currently I am overriding the volume keys with `dispatchKeyEvent` because `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` were not working.  Throughout the application there are little dialogs or context menus that pop up.  The problem is when those take focus I lose control of the volume buttons and it adjusts the main volume instead of acting like my button.  Is there any way to completely take over the volume buttons?  Any help would be appreciated.

-mlove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a listener of type `DialogInterface.OnKeyListener` and set it on your dialogs with `setOnKeyListener` to capture the volume keys.

Comment: This is excellent and perfect timing!  Thanks for you help - it works perfectly!

Comment: This worked for a dialog but I have found that I can't get to the view that made the options menu.  When the menu pops up the volume keys do what the system wants again.  Any ideas on how to add a OnKeyListener to a menu?

Comment: sorry, i dont know about menu keys, but did you have a look at Menu.isShortcutKey(int, android.view.KeyEvent), http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#isShortcutKey%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29 ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay on the response I did not see the post until now.  I took a look at it but was not able to make any progress with it.  I'll keep searching.